# multiple textures into one texture

Tags: textures, maps

Can i fusion multiple .tga or .jpeg into only one, and texturise my model with it ?

Here is an example to explain my self better :  I have Mr Bowser as 3d model and i want to integrate it in a game. The thing is that all the textures, from the color of his mouth to the cones on his shell are held by different tga files. For the mouth i have mouth.tga as texture, for the cones on the shell i have cone.tga and so on... . But what i want to achieve is to have cone.tga mouth.tga and so on, in the same and only file. Like all the textures to make Mr angry Bowser a colorfull character concentrated in one and only file.
Can i achieve that, is there a way to do it ?

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely can combine them! Many 3D games contain an image for the characters body and one for the head, and some combine the two for a single texture for the entire a model. Here's an example of a whole head's texture:

[image]

Also check out [this PDF](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g/lectures/lecture12-Texture_mapping.pdf) if you'd like to learn more about texture mapping in general.

Comment: Great Thank you ! Hope your answer will help others.